# Skip lines in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just started learning. Trying to figure out how to skip a line in the `Times = (Times * int(Random_Number))`,

to be something like :

```
print(Times)

print(Times)
```

Etc..

```
Year = input("Now's year : ")
name= input("Enter your name: ")
Initial_age= float(input(("Enter your age: ")))

Final_age= float(Year) + (100 - Initial_age)
Times =(name+ " You're turning"+ " 100 at year " + str(Final_age))

Random_Number = (input("Enter a random number: "))
Times = (Times * int(Random_Number))

print(Times)
```

Comment: Use `\n` to insert new line.

Comment: What lines are you talking about? What output do you expect?

Comment: Perhaps `Times = (Times + '\n') * int (Random_Number)`? Although it would be simpler to just call `print` in a loop that executes `int(Random_Number)` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print each `NAME You're turning 100 at year XXXX` on a new line, like this

```
John You're turning 100 at year 2109.0
John You're turning 100 at year 2109.0
John You're turning 100 at year 2109.0
John You're turning 100 at year 2109.0
```

Add a `\n` at the end here

```
Times = name + " You're turning 100 at year " + str(Final_age) + "\n"
```

---

But the nicest is to use a loop, and a `print` inside of it

```
year          = int(input("Now's year : "))
name          = input("Enter your name: ")
initial_age   = int(input("Enter your age: "))
random_number = int(input("Enter a random number: "))

final_age = year + 100 - initial_age
for i in range(random_number):
    print(name, "You're turning 100 at year", final_age)
```